# My Android Java isn't loading photos off-screen?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

My Android Java code gets photos from Facebook and displays them. It changes the X and Y values for each photo, displaying 4 per row. this is fine, but when it gets to printing photos with a Y value greater than the screen's height, it stops printing them. There is no error, but I can't scroll down to see them. Is there a solution?

```
   public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                    JSONObject photos = response.getJSONObject();
                    JSONArray data = photos.optJSONArray("data");
                    int x1 = 0;
                    int y1 = 0;
                    boolean first1 = true;
                    for(int i =0;i<data.length();i++) {
                        if(x1==0&&first1==false){
                            x1 = 310;

                        }
                        else if(x1==310){
                            x1=620;

                        }
                        else if(x1==620){
                            x1=930;
                        }
                        else if(x1==930){
                            x1=0;
                            y1 = y1+310;
                        }

                        first1=false;
                        JSONObject link = data.optJSONObject(i);
                        String link2 = link.optString("picture");
                        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
                        params.leftMargin = x1;
                        params.topMargin = y1;
                        URL path = null;
                        try {
                            path = new URL(link2);
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Bitmap image = null;
                   GridView grid1 =    (GridView)           findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
                        try {
                            image =     BitmapFactory.decodeStream(path.openConnection().getInputStream());
                            image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 300, 300, false);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
                        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RL1);

                        rl.addView(imageView, params);
                    }
```

Comment: Seems you are just adding them to a relative layout which is not really scrollable by default

Comment: Oh okay. So any suggestions on how to fix that? Sorry if I appear stupid, I only started Android last week.

Comment: You could just use a GridView with a custom Adapter to get the gallery type of layout that you want and it allows you to specify the horizontal and vertical spacing of each item in the list and does scrolling for you too.

Comment: Oh okay. I also saw something about a scroll view? It looks simpler, but would it do the same thing?

Comment: A scrollview would allow you to scroll as well but the GridView would give you more control over your data set. If you really just want to use the scrollview then you would have to add a child to that layout perhaps a linearlayout with Vertical orientation then add a horizontal linearlayout which you populate with your imageviews just like you have it set out there currently.

Comment: Ya. Okay, I'll try scroll view and see how it works. Thanks.